# Updating DB after a file in a dicertory is changed

Tags: php, mysql, file

Consider following scenario:
You a a folder (F) that contain some files. Some metadata is save in these file and a DB have a table of these metada . When a file is changed we want the DB changed automatically to reflect these changes.Files is changed via OS facilities (not php).

What is best practice to implement the scenario?

Comment: How long may it take for the changes to be implemented into the database/how many times per day do you want to check this? (ever thought of a cronjob)?

Comment: @dragon112 Approximately one check per hour, I whould beter that changes could be commented instantly

Answer (score 0):

If you can, the **OS facilities should trigger** the php script to update DB.

The heavier way would be to monitor the folder for changes, from a cronjob, or a more realtime service like **Hot Folders** feature from [SOS Job Scheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=72&page=osource_scheduler_features_en.htm#hot_folders) e.g